# c++ identifier not found when compiling source

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int userInput = -9999;
    userInput = ReadNumber();
    WriteAnswer(userInput);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};

int ReadNumber ()
{
    int liInput = -9999;
    cin >> liInput;
    return liInput;
};

 void WriteAnswer(int data)
{
    cout << data << endl;
};
```

When I try to compile, it saids :

1>error C3861: 'ReadNumber': identifier not found

1>error C3861: 'WriteAnswer': identifier not found

Why did the above error occurs? and how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ sources are compiled **from beginning to end**.

When the compiler has gotten this far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int userInput = -9999;
    userInput = ReadNumber();   // <-- What is this?
```

It's true -- there is no evidence of `ReadNumber` existing.

Declare the existence of your functions before they are used.

```
int ReadNumber ();
void WriteAnswer(int data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to type function prototypes.

```
int ReadNumber ( void );
void WriteAnswer(int );
```

Put them in your code before calling the functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you try to call `ReadNumber` function, that hasn't been declared yet. The compiler doesn't know anything about this function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ...
    ReadNumber();   // call to function ReadNumber, but what is ReadNumber ??? 
}

// definition of ReadNumber:
int ReadNumber ()
{
    ...
}
```

You should declare it first:

```
// declaration:
int ReadNumber();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ...
    ReadNumber();   // call ReadNumber that takes no arguments and returns int
}

// definition of ReadNumber:
int ReadNumber ()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **have to write** a function prototype or function itself before first call of the function.

In your code compiler see call of the `ReadNumber()` but it doesn't know what is that function.